# iOS Charts: Grid Lines Drawing issue

Tags: swift2, ios-charts

I am trying to enable grid lines using the iOS Charts Library to eventually achieve something like this

[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwHpD.png)

My code so far

func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

```
    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    let yAxis = lineChartView.getAxis(.Left)
    let yAxisRight = lineChartView.getAxis(.Right)

    let xAxis = lineChartView.xAxis

    lineChartView.drawBordersEnabled = true

    xAxis.spaceBetweenLabels = 1
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    xAxis.gridLineWidth = 0.25

    yAxisRight.enabled = false
    yAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    yAxis.axisMaxValue = 4.0
    yAxis.axisMinValue = 1.0
    yAxis.inverted = true
    yAxis.setLabelCount(4, force: true)
    yAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    var dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: 1.0, xIndex: 0)
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: 1.0, xIndex: 1)
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: 2.0, xIndex: 1)
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: 2.0, xIndex: 2)
    dataEntries.append(dataEntry)

    let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let lineChartData = LineChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
    lineChartView.data = lineChartData

}
```

//my result

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Udu.png)

Grid lines do not appear to be drawing. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't see a problem - on your result image grid lines are drawn

Answer (score 0):

Your grid lines may be too thin - and on devices with lower resolutions it may result in not showing the lines at all.

An iPhone 6 or 6 plus will show a line for 0.25 pixels... But earlier devices won't.